# why component disappear when i change tab?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuex

in my laravel project i have used Vuejs and Vuex.when page is loaded or refreshed then component is displayed but when i change tab and goto previous tab then component disappear.And when i goto next page and return back everything is fine.

```
below is component featured.vue

<template>
<div class="featured_slider slider">
<h4>featured</h4>
<div class="featured_slider_item" v-for="product in getFeaturedProducts">
<div class="border_active"></div>
<div class="product_item discount d-flex flex-column align-items-center 
justify-content-center text-center">
<div class="product_image d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify- 
content-center">
<img :src="'/Uploads/Products/'+product.id+'/cropped_'+product.image.name" 
:alt="product.image.name"></div>
<div class="product_content">
<div class="product_price discount">Rs.{{product.price_old}}<span>Rs. 
{{product.price_new}}</span></div>
<div class="product_name">
<div><a href="#">{{product.title}}</a></div>`
</div>
<div class="product_extras">
<div class="product_color">
<input type="radio" checked 
name="product_color"style="background:#b19c83">
<input type="radio" name="product_color"
style="background:#000000">
<input type="radio" name="product_color"
style="background:#999999">
</div>
<button class="product_cart_button">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
</div>
<div class="product_fav"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i></div>
<ul class="product_marks">
<li class="product_mark product_discount">-25%</li>
<li class="product_mark product_new">new</li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
data(){
return{
products:[]
}
},
computed:{
getFeaturedProducts(){
return this.$store.getters.featuredProducts;
}
},
created() {
return this.$store.dispatch('featuredProducts');
}
}
</script>
```

below is state.js

```
export default {
featuredProducts:[],
onSale:[]
}
```

below is getters.js

```
export const featuredProducts= state =>{
//console.log(state);
return state.featuredProducts
};

export const onSale= state =>{
//console.log(state);
return state.onSale
};
```

below is mutations.js

```
export const featuredProducts=(state,responseData)=>{
state.featuredProducts=responseData;
// console.log(responseData)
};

export const onSale=(state,responseData)=>{
state.onSale=responseData;
// console.log(responseData)
};
```

below is actions.js

```
import {sendGet} from "../../../utils/request";
export const featuredProducts =context=>{
sendGet('/product/products').then(response=>{
context.commit('featuredProducts',response.data.data)
});
};

export const onSale =context=>{
sendGet('/product/onsale').then(response=>{
context.commit('onSale',response.data.data)
});
};
```

Comment: some code maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Considering general file structure `'public>js>app.js'`, `app.js`
 which include all compiled js, the vue dependencies and attach vue instance to to
 the body of the page,  your blade, eg `index.blade.php` you might have something like ::

`<script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>`

In your blade template, change it into something like this, considering same file structure:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('js')}}/app.js"></script>`